# Bootstrap row how to center images with different width/height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, image-size

I have a web page. I would like to add 6 images in a row with different width and height. I want to place those images inside border with equal margins from both sides/borders. I think I have to get the biggest image width and height and set to the others. I don't want to spread out the image outside the border.

Here is my demo page:
http://s14.postimg.org/5mh3d728x/sample.png

EdiT 1: here is sample html

```
 <div class="row" style="padding-left: 40px;">
        <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
            <img src="img/bulutistan.jpg" style="width: 78px; padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 12px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
            <img src="img/datamarket.jpg" style="width: 105px; padding-top: 32px; padding-bottom: 25px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
            <img src="img/esq.jpg" style="width: 104px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 17px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
            <img src="img/libelium.jpg" style="width: 103px; padding-bottom: 24px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
            <img src="img/microsoft.jpg" style="width: 53px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
            <img src="img/turkcell.jpg" style="width: 102px; padding-top: 26px; padding-bottom: 27px;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.thumbnailImage {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 4px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 7px;
        }
```

EdiT 2: If I changed it to the below, images are getting bigger. I want to maintain the original image sizes.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row text-center" style="padding-left: 30em;">
                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
                    <img src="images/bulutistan.png" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
                    <img src="images/datamarket.png" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
                    <img src="images/esq.png" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
                    <img src="images/libelium.png" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
                    <img src="images/microsoft.png" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage">
                    <img src="images/turkcell.png" >
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.thumbnailImage {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 4px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 7px;
        }
.thumbnailImage img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      min-height: 150px;
    }
```

Here is the screenshot:http://s21.postimg.org/gslnddahj/sample2.png

**EdiT 3: I tried the javascript solution but images get bigger, not centered and div exceeds the screen.**

Here is the screenshot:http://s7.postimg.org/m7mxh36qj/sample3.png

Here is the final HTML:
 **

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 ">
                    <img src="images/bulutistan.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 ">
                    <img src="images/datamarket.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 ">
                    <img src="images/esq.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 ">
                    <img src="images/libelium.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 ">
                    <img src="images/microsoft.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 ">
                    <img src="images/turkcell.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
```

**

**EdiT 4: Here is the final markup and CSS. I wonder if there is a way to make images fit in one row.**

The sample demo: http://s12.postimg.org/647dighkt/sample.png

HTML:

```
 <div class="row equal" >

                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage imgc">
                    <img src="images/bulutistan.png" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage imgc">
                    <img src="images/datamarket.png" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage imgc">
                    <img src="images/esq.png" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage imgc">
                    <img src="images/libelium.png" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage imgc">
                    <img src="images/microsoft.png" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 thumbnailImage imgc">
                    <img src="images/turkcell.png" >
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
div.imgc img{
   display:block;
   margin:auto;
}
```

Thanks in advance & Best Regards.

Comment: show some code which you've tried yet.

Comment: @Leothelion sample html added.

Comment: @KevinAndrid samle html added.

Comment: @Leothelion actually I do want to have fixed height and width for the borders. Thats why I said I guess I need to the the biggest image height and width. (Heightest is 155px and widthest is 127 px.)

Comment: For your Edit 3, It's because you have not set the `.img-responsive` class on your images I think.

Comment: @Haeresis it was there, see my edit please.

Comment: Try to add that into img-responsive: `.img-responsive {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}` or redefine img-responsive like that `.img-responsive {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}` and apply `text-align: center;` on parent.

Comment: @Haeresis redefining as you suggested worked for IE 11. I mean images are at the center but in FF and chrome they are placed at the right a little bit. And I need to reduce padding right and left.

Comment: @Haeresis Is there a way to make images look a little bit smaller? They are not fit on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this method as exposed on

- **[this Live Responsive Exemple](http://codepen.io/Haeresis/pen/NxNXLo)**

All your images will be Responsive thanks to Bootstrap `.img-responsive` OOCSS Class Pattern. That mean will be have the real size if your column have enought space. In Mobile, this images will be horizontaly center and each image to be displayed to a new line.

But above 992px (as you setted with `md` Bootstrap), the behavior you want is applied and each image will be verticaly centered into column (and each column will be have the same height).

On this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://lh6.ggpht.com/SeHZRXds3ossNP6yOrniffP0m7LcfONuzuy4uHQGfe1PT9B0SXIlGP0vExImCo38MM0=w300">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/1d/89/3e/1d893e8180f8b57988f4ffa1188bb015.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/1d/89/3e/1d893e8180f8b57988f4ffa1188bb015.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://lh6.ggpht.com/SeHZRXds3ossNP6yOrniffP0m7LcfONuzuy4uHQGfe1PT9B0SXIlGP0vExImCo38MM0=w300">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/RxProdoIP2t3XhpSjNlJix9rL23mKTA7APWYoV-D9W3wLXP3S4jiM7X4Z5_M5gVA31k=h900">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/RxProdoIP2t3XhpSjNlJix9rL23mKTA7APWYoV-D9W3wLXP3S4jiM7X4Z5_M5gVA31k=h900">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.col-md-2 {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.img-responsive {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .img-responsive {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

Create this JavaScript function:

```
/**
 * Maintain the height of all object in htmlCollection.
 * @function maintainedSameHeight
 * @param  {HTMLCollection} htmlCollection - All HTMLElement need to kept the same height.
 * @param  {string}         mediaQueries   - Under what responsive condition the calcul is apply.
 */
function maintainedSameHeight(htmlCollection, mediaQueries) {
  var maxHeight = 0;

  [].forEach.call(htmlCollection, function(htmlElement) {
    htmlElement.style.height = "";
    maxHeight = (htmlElement.offsetHeight > maxHeight) ? htmlElement.offsetHeight : maxHeight;
  });

  if (!mediaQueries || window.matchMedia(mediaQueries).matches) {
    [].forEach.call(htmlCollection, function(htmlElement) {
      htmlElement.style.height = maxHeight + "px";
    });
  }
};
```

And apply it:

```
/* Create a function to apply on the `.col-md-1` already in the DOM the previous created function. */
function setHeightOnImages() {
  maintainedSameHeight(
        // Target all column you want inspect to find the most height.
        document.querySelectorAll(".col-md-2"),
        // Because under 992px, you will be have one column, there are no necessity to maintain same height in this case.
        "(min-width: 992px)"
  );
}

/* Apply at first time. */
window.addEventListener("load", setHeightOnImages);
/* And update in case of Responsive. */
window.addEventListener("resize", setHeightOnImages);
```

Comment: I would at least debounce the setHeightOnImages(). To have less calls to it.

Comment: The goal of `setHeightOnImages` is to apply the same behavior after each event you want. So if you want call this function one time or write several time the content in `maintainedSameHeight` you can. But why :)

Comment: The reason you need to debounce the function on resize is because like this your function gets called a lot while resizing. But it would be better(for performance) to call the function after the resize event has finished. Look at this for a visual representation of what a debounce function does: http://drupalmotion.com/article/debounce-and-throttle-visual-explanation

Comment: @Haeresis, i tried your solution but images get bigger and not centered. Please check my edit 3 on my original post.

Comment: `img-responsive` allow your image to never be more bigger than the container.
you must surcharge that Bootstrap class to allow it to be centered with `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto`.It's what I do here http://codepen.io/Haeresis/pen/NxNXLo Or it's also possible to pass the `display: inline-block` to allow parent `text-align: center` to work.

Comment: @yeouuu It's not a part of Vanilla JS so I don't use it and it's not the purpose of that question but it also possible to load some script like http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ and use that `window.addEventListener("resize", Cowboy.debounce(250, setHeightOnImages));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class text-center on your row div.

```
<div class="row text-center" style="padding-left: 40px;">
```

and in css:

```
.thumbnailImage img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gvpy9egs/1/

if you want the height fixed on a certain amount, you could just do it like this:

```
.thumbnailImage {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.thumbnailImage img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 25px;
  min-height: 25px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gvpy9egs/3/

I personally think it's overkill to do this in javascript, and update it onresize.

Comment: Your solution makes images smaller. I would like to preserve the original sizes of the images.

Comment: Idd you are right. In that case, you have 2 options imo. Either you go with javascript which runs everytime you resize as Haeresis demonstrated.
Or you could calculate thumbnails on your backend. If you cache this calculated result, you only need to recalculate when your image set changes.

Comment: @yeouuu actually there will be only 6 images, no more.

Comment: @yeouuu is there a way to fit the images in one row? Please check my edit4.